# Open new window - tkinter/tk taskbar/dock

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, taskbar, dock

How can I can a function and create a function for the icon context menu? I want to make the iconic `Open New Window` function pop-up when you right click on the icon menu in the taskbar/dock. [See this question for more info on this kind of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72280411/tkinter-taskbar-dock-icon-menu).

Places I have looked but found nothing:

- https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/tk_mac.html#M15
- https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/feature-notes.html#open-event-handling-in-a-tkinter-based-gui-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are a tiny subset of [apple events](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/tk_mac.html) that you can benefit from the [DockMenu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocktileplugin/1527547-dockmenu) **is not accessible directly via tkinter**. Turns out mac is not really open for modifications and even [smaller tasks can be hard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30009909/13629335). You could consider to use a [system tray icon](https://pystray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) instead.

Comment: Very interesting. There is no functionality for this in tk itself? I am intrigued by the idea of a system tray icon but and wondering if I can call on the DockMenu using pyobjc. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @TRCK I have no experience with mac and cant help you further more to gain progress. I just was interested in the tkinter relationship. But I can tell that I use win32 to make similar *extensions* to my applications, it can be frustrating and hard, but in the end it is your app. Hope you will find a way, happy codeing.

Comment: @TRCK [Found you something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517639/13629335)

Comment: @TRCK just came across [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html#gui-programming-on-the-mac) where quote: *PyObjC is a Python binding to Apple’s Objective-C/Cocoa framework, which is the foundation of most modern Mac development. Information on PyObjC is available from https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc/.* thought it would be interesting for you. Also would be nice if you accept this answer.